# kernel of the tangent map of $p\colon G\to G/H$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H$ a closed subgroup. Let $p\,\colon G\to G/H$ the canonical map (here $G/H$ is just considered as a set). There is a proposition saying that $G/H$ can be equipped with a smooth structure of a smooth manifold such that $p$ is a submersion. Actually, I can fully understand that $G/H$ will be a smooth manifold of dimension $\mathrm{dim}(G)-\mathrm{dim}(H)$ but I cannot see clearly why $p$ should be submersion. My definition of submersion is that the tangent maps are surjective. So, we need to prove that the image has dimension $\mathrm{dim}(G)-\mathrm{dim}(H)$. Let $T_{g}p\,\colon T_{g}G\to T_{gH}G/H$. By linear algebra, $\mathrm{dim}(G)=\mathrm{dim}(T_{g}G)=\mathrm{dim}(\ker T_{g}p)+\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Im}\,T_{g}p)$. Is it obvious that $\ker T_{g}p=T_{g}H$? I cannot prove it rigorously.

(H of course is a Lie subgroup since it is a closed subgroup of G).

Comment: You can found the full proof on Jack Lee's smooth manifold book Theorem 21.10 (Quotient Manifold Theorem) which locally construct a chart such the map is projection map therefore submersion.

Comment: You say "G/H is just considered as a set", but just to clarify: That's still the group theory quotient, not the set theory / topology quotient, right? Even though we don't care about the group _structure_ on G/H.

Comment: @Arthur yes of course, but someone could get confused because we do not assume $H$ to be normal.

Comment: $G/H=\{gH\,|\,g\in G\}$ and $gH=\{gh\,|\,h\in H\}$

Comment: @yili I do not think this is exactly what I want. Your theorem says that we have a Lie group acting freely and properly on a smooth manifold $M$ and then he takes the orbit space $M/G$. But do we have this case in my question? And to be honest, I am pretty lost to this proof, I think there is just an easy argument for my question.

Comment: hi T. Wildwolf , I am a beginner at differential geometry, but you know the quotient of manifold needs not to be smooth. The free and proper condition is needed to guarantee the exitence of smooth structure.

Comment: Do you know Sard's theorem?

Comment: @JasonDeVito How can this help? The set of all critical points has measure zero.

Comment: I can write an answer using it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\pi:G\rightarrow G/H$ is surjective.  By Sard's theorem, there is a regular point $g_0 H\in G/H$.  That is, the map $T_{g_0} \pi: T_{g_0}G\rightarrow T_{g_0H}G/H$ is surjective for at least one $g_0\in G$.

Now, let's promote this to all of $G$.

**Proposition:**  The map $\pi$ has constant rank.  In particular, since it has full rank at one point, it must have full rank everywhere.

**Proof:**  Given any $g\in H$, consider the maps $L_g:G\rightarrow G$ and $L'_g:G/H\rightarrow G/H$ given by $L_g(g') = gg'$ and $L'_g( g'H) = (gg')H$.  Then both $L_g$ and $L'_g$ are diffeomorphisms with inverses $(L_g)^{-1} = L_{g^{_1}}$ and $(L'_g)^{-1} = L'_{g^{-1}}$.

A simple computation reveals $$L'_g \circ \pi = \pi \circ L_g.$$

Taking the derivative of the main equation at the identity $e\in G$, we find $$T_{eH} L'_g \circ T_e \pi = T_g \pi \circ T_e L_g.$$  Call this the main equation.

Since $L'_g$ is a diffeomorphism, $T_{eH}L'_g$ is an isomorphism, so we can rewrite this as $T_e \pi = (T_{eH} L'_g)^{-1}\circ T_g\pi \circ T_e L_g$.  Taking $g = g_0$, the right hand side is a composition of surjective maps, so $T_e \pi$ is also surjective.

Returning to the main equation (with arbitrary $g$), we can now use the fact that $T_e L_g$ is invertible to rewrite this as $$T_{eH} L'_g\circ T_e\pi \circ (T_e L_g)^{-1} = T_g \pi.$$  This is again a composition of surjectiv maps, so is surjective.  Since $g$ is arbitrary, we are done.  $\square$

Now that we know that map is constant rank, it follows automatically that for each $g$, $\ker T_g \pi$ has the same dimension as $T_g H$ (which I'm interpreting as $T_e L_g (\mathfrak{h})$ with $\mathfrak{h} = T_e H$).  Thus, in order to show that $T_g H = \ker T_g \pi$, we only need to show that $T_g H\subseteq \ker T_g \pi$.

To that end, let $X\in T_g H$.  Then there is a $Y\in \mathfrak{h}$ with $X = T_e L_g Y$.  Then $g\exp(tY)$ is a path through $g$ with derivative $X$ at time $0$.  Note that $\exp(tY)\in H$ for all $t$.

Now we compute:  $\pi(g\exp(tY)) = (g\exp(tY))H = gH$, so $\pi \circ (g\exp(tY))$ is constant, and has derivative zero.  This means that $T_g H\subseteq \ker T_g \pi$, so we conclude that $T_g H = \ker T_g \pi$ as desired.

Comment: To be honest, can you describe exactly the argument "By Sard's theorem there is at least..." to be honest, I do not think I know how to apply exactly the Sard's theorem. Maybe you should also explain what a critical point is because we might have different definitions. You could also reffer everything to a book so that I can double check them.

Comment: I don't have direct book references on hand, but I suspect everything can be found in Lee's Smooth Manifolds book (it's where I learned all this from.)  Regarding Sard's theorem, here are my definitions:  Given a smooth ($C^\infty$) function $f:M\rightarrow N$ between smooth manifolds $M$ and $N$, a point $x\in M$ is called a critical point of $f$ if $T_x f$ is *not* surjective, and it's called a regular point of $f$ if $T_x f$ is surjective.  A point $y\in N$ is called a regular value of $f$ if every point $x\in f^{-1}(y)$ (that is, every point with $f(x) = y$) is a regular point of $f$.

Comment: @T.Wildwolf:  (One version of) Sard's theorem asserts that if $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a smooth ($C^\infty$) map between smooth manifolds, then the set of regular values has full measure in $N$.  In particular, there is a regular value.

Comment: So I think I should revise some stuff in order to understand the last comment but thanks